# Dynamically add views to fragment hosted by Viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'd like to add 7 previously created views dynamically to my viewpager.

What I try to achieve at the end is a part of my screen (50dp height, match_parent width) looking like this.

---

|   VIEW 1   |   VIEW 2   |

---

When I swipe to the right, the displayed items will be VIEW 2 and VIEW 3, next swipe will be VIEW 3 and VIEW 4 and so on.

My problem is that my 7 views are already created in the onCreateView of my main fragment. I'd like to add them dynamically to my fragment defined in the FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private View view1Layout;
    private View view2Layout;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, View view1Layout, View view2Layout) {
        super(fm);
        this.view1Layout = view1Layout;
        this.view2Layout = view2Layout;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();

        LinearLayout rootLayout = ((LinearLayout) fragment.getView().getRootView());

        switch (position % 7) {
            case 0:
                rootLayout.addView(view1Layout);
                rootLayout.addView(view2Layout);
                break;
            case 1:
                // ....
                break;
        }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1000;
    }
}


public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dashboard_line, container, false);
    }
}
```

As you can imagine, it will crash when I try to get the rootLayout, as the fragment is not instantiated at this time. Is there a good way to achieve what I want or a workaround if not ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it in the wrong way...

I should not pass view even if it was more convenient in my case, but I should pass data contained in those views and refresh them according the displayed fragment.